# how to fix relationship error between models?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have set up two models and made the relationship between them. I want to pass the attributes of the user as well as the `user_detail`.

I have used a similar code somewhere and it worked perfectly. But it is not working here.

```
//This is the function in "User.php" model.
public function user_detail(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}

//This is the function in "Profile.php" model.
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

//edit function in ProfileController
public function edit($id)
{
    $user=User::find($id);
    return view('profile.edit')->with('data',$user->user_detail);
}
```

When I click the edit button in the view, I expect the extract all the details from user table as well as from `user_detail` table.

Comment: What is your exact Laravel version?

Comment: Are you sure has a ``user_id`` field on your ``profiles`` table?

Comment: no, I am using student number as user_id. I have student no. on both tables and are unique, but not the primary key. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

try using `where` instead of `find` and then use `with`:

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->with('user_detail')->first();
return view('profile.edit')->with('data', $user);
```

In your **model**:

```
public function user_detail(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile', 'student_no');
}
```

Comment: the model name is Profile but table name is user_detail. user_detail as $id,student_no,email,CID, etc. i am trying to show data of same student number in user table and userr_detail table.

Comment: I edited my answer, can you try it again and tell me if it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your this code a little bit

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user=User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('profile.edit')->with('data',$user);
}
```

And in your blade file (profile.edit), You can get all details from User and Profile Model.

```
{{ $data->id }}
{{ $data->user_detail->YOURPARAMETERS }}
```

Comment: This is not working. could you look for another solution? I am still stuck on this issue.

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your database schema?

Comment: i have 2 tables. Users table and user_detail table. i have student number on both the tables which is not primary key but is unique. both tables have other details such as email, CID, name, etc..

Comment: If there is no primary key then it causes a problem to manage a relationship. Please update your question with database schema so we can help you exactly from there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the relationship naming. Make it camelCase like,

```
//This is the function in "User.php" model.
public function userDetail(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}

//edit function in ProfileController
public function edit($id)
{
    $user=User::find($id);
    return view('profile.edit')->with('data',$user->userDetail);
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/4307#issuecomment-42037712

Comment: it is not must, it should be an advice. I can use as ``function_name`` of method name always.

Comment: Yes. But Laravel 4.2 enforces this. That's why I asked his Laravel version.

Comment: I have even tried with camelCase. it's not working. Another approach, please!

Comment: Then please share your schema as well.